# How can I create a text box on iOS/Android and handle the input in MonoGame?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monogame

I want that people can create a new account in my MonoGame iOS and Android application. I need a text box for username, password and recovery e-mail address (if someone forgot his password).

- How can I create the text box? Should I make a white rectangle sprite (`Texture2D`) and a `spriteFont` to write the text (for example the username)?
  Or are there better ways to create the text box?
- How can I find out if someone tapped with his finger on the blank text box? Can I use `Rectangle.Intersects(TappRectangle)` or is it better to do this differently?
- How can I show the keyboard on iOS/Android after someone tapped on the text box so that they can write their username in the textbox?
- How can I get the characters they tapped on the keyboard?
- Is it possible to save/remember the text(login data) so that people don't need to write it always when they start my application? I want that the text boxes are already filled out with their login credentials when they start the application, then they would just need to tap on a login button to log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `KeyboardInput.Show(string WindowTitle, string Prompt, string Default, bool HidePassword = false)` method.

```
// Load saved data into the following variables:
var defaultUsername = "";
var defaultPassword = "";
var defaultEmail = "";

var username = await KeyboardInput.Show("Name", "What's your username?", defaultUsername);
var password = await KeyboardInput.Show("Password", "What's your Password?", defaultPassword, true);
var email = await KeyboardInput.Show("E-Mail", "What's your Email?", defaultEmail);

// validate and save if the values do not match the defaults above
```

This will show three separate input boxes, but it handles prompts and pop-up keyboard display and input.

As far as saving the data: Look at the [TitleContainer](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/TitleContainer.cs) class. You can use standard file I/O to read and write the data.